# Downsample 3 Dolby Digital channels (Front, Center, Right) to stereo?

Tags: ffmpeg, ac3, dolbydigital

I've got a Dolby Digital (ac3) file and I'm able to extract channels one by one like this:

```
-map_channel 0.0.4 -channel_layout mono -sn -b:a 128k -ac 1
```

For example, this extracts the back left channel.

I want to make a good stereo sound from the front three channels (Front, Center, Right) without the back channels - I'm going to play those through another amp. My thoughts are copying some/all of the center channel onto the left/right channels of the stereo output?

I can't downsample 5.1 to 2 in one go because I don't want the back left/right channels to bleed into the front. I want a stereo output of the three front channels, if that helps.

This is the ac3 channel layout:

```
0 FRONT_LEFT
1 FRONT_RIGHT
2 FRONT_CENTER
3 LOW_FREQUENCY
4 BACK_LEFT
5 BACK_RIGHT
```

Help is *greatly* appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you come up with the process, whatever it may be, I suggest lowering volume of center channel by 6 decibels before merging into each the left and right channels. Reason: 6 decibels is half, and since you are going to be playing it through two speakers instead of one, you'll get double the output and it will overpower L/R instead of blending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [pan filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan):

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "pan=stereo|FL<FL+0.5*FC|FR<FR+0.5*FC[a]" -map 0:v? -map "[a]" -c:v copy output
```

- Remove or adjust the FC multiplication factors to desired levels.
- Using `>` instead of `=`, as shown in the example, will adjust the gain to be renormalized so that the total is 1, thus avoiding clipping noise.
- Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channel Manipulation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation).